# Can transparency on symbols be set within symbology, or only on the whole layer, in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, transparency-opacity

I can see [how to vary transparency of a whole layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/set-layer-properties.htm), and also [how to vary transparency by attribute](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/vary-symbology-by-transparency.htm).

Assuming that I have set my layer symbology to use Unique Values (e.g., different point colors depending on whether `VALUE` is A, B, or C), is it possible to set transparency on a symbology level (e.g., A and B are 25% transparent, C is 75% transparent)? I can't use `VALUE` as the transparency by attribute field, because it's not numerical.

Comment: not from within the layer properties -> symbology as far as im aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more tedious way to do it, but it's within symbology. Select the symbology with unique values [image: image1] 
click on the color and select the symbol icon(the one with a brush), select the colors drop arrow and select color proprieties and there you will find a transparency slider.[image: image with trasparency slider].

Comment: Man, this stuff is really well buried. Nice find.

Answer (score 4):

(Well, I figured this out right after posting...)

It actually does work by combining [varying transparency by attribute](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/vary-symbology-by-transparency.htm) with an Arcade expression.

In the symbology dialog, instead of simply choosing a Field, create an Arcade expression:

```
if ($feature.VALUE == 'C') {
  return 1
}
else {
  return 0
}
```

The transparency of "high values" (anything with `VALUE == C`) and "low values" can then be set in the Transparency Range dialog.

[image]

Comment: have you determined a way to then set labels on the legend back to text? For example, I used an expression to set "low confidence" to 80% transparent and "high confidence" to not transparent at all, but the numbers on the legend are meaningless to my users.